# quieter findbugs console output in case of errors

Tags: java, ant, findbugs

I am running [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) (release 3.0.0) from the command line using the [Ant findbugs task](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html).
What I see in case of detected code smells is the following:

[image]

As you can see at the conclusion of the `Ant` invocation and verify with the `echo $?` line,  the build was successful with an exit code of `0` however `findbugs` apparently invokes a Java program and outputs a needlessly alerting message. People running my build process might pause and wonder whether the build succeeded or not. I've set the `quiteerrors` property to `true` but it doesn't seem to do anything in this regard:

```
<target name="findbugs" depends="build, dry-findbugs"/>
<target name="dry-findbugs">
    <taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"   classpath="${ant.deps.dir}/findbugs-ant.jar"      />
    <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}"
              output="${findbugs.output}"
              effort="max" reportLevel="low" quieterrors="true"
              outputFile="${findbugs.outputDir}/findbug.html" >
        <auxClasspath>
            <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </auxClasspath>
        <sourcePath path="${basedir}/src" />
        <class location="${dist.jar.file}"/>
    </findbugs>
</target>
```

Is there a way to instruct `findbugs` to be more discrete when reporting that code smells were detected?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *quiet**E**rrors=true*, with a capital *E*?